# Safari text box not taking any input

Tags: javascript, safari, event-handling, onkeydown

I had an issue in safari 5.1 browser where the modal window was printing 2 chars if u press the key. To solve that issue i wrote this script

```
var isSafari51;
isSafari51 = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
if (isSafari51){
    tem = navigator.userAgent.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i);
    if (tem[1] === "5.1"){
        document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
            if (evt.keyCode == 8 || evt.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 9 )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the modal window text boxes are taking the inputs correctly but the normal input type text are not taking any inputs. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just added a check " window.opener != null " to returns a reference to the window that created the window. And it worked